# Using CONVERT from Imagemagick in PHP page

Tags: php, imagemagick

I'm attempting to pull files from a directory, compress them, and then display them on my web page. The files are direct uploads from my Digital Camera (when I'm travelling via my iPad) so I cannot shrink them on my computer.

Anyhow, I cannot for the life of me get this to work after many hours of scouring the net.

```
<?php

echo "<BR><BR>";
$dir = opendir('images/day1/'); 
while ($read = readdir($dir)) 
{

if ($read!='.' && $read!='..') 
{ 
echo $read;
exec( 'convert $read -quality 50 $output' );
echo "<BR>";
echo '<a href="images/day1/'.$read.'" TARGET="_BLANK"><img src="'.$output.'" WIDTH="800"></a>'; 
echo '<BR><BR>';
}

}

closedir($dir); 
?>
```

Any and all suggestions welcomed .... I simply cannot get the convert to work (assign a lesser quality then display the $output.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Why aren't you using the ImageMagick extension in PHP?

Comment: What are the symptoms?

Comment: I have imagemagick (on shared server) but no access to imagick. My host said I need a VPS package to get it. If there is another way to read a directory of jpg's , compress them on the fly, and echo them onto my webpage .. I'm all ears. At the moment, I just cannot get the image to appear, at all ...

Comment: You have access to the convert executable but not the imagemagick php extension? Try using the full path of the "convert" executable

Answer (score 1):

```
<?php 
$photo="sunflower.jpg"; 

$cmd = "convert $photo -quality 50 JPG:-"; 

header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
passthru($cmd, $retval); 
?>
```

On a page of its own and can only view the one image or you can have a

```
<img src="php_page_containing_above_code.php?photo=sunflower.jpg">
```

and have lots more images.
Comment out the $photo variable at the top of the code and I can not remember the exact code at the moment and am at work so can not test it. I do not think you need $photo = $_GET['photo']; but again can not remember as I do not use this method.

---

**Code example added when the OP said the first piece did not work.**

Save this as image.php

```
<?php 
$photo = $_REQUEST['photo'];
$cmd = "convert $photo -quality 50 JPG:-"; 
header("Content-type: image/jpeg"); 
passthru($cmd, $retval); 
?>
```

Save this as whatever you want and run:

```
<?php
// Directory to read images from
$dir = "background/";

// Read the directory and sellect EVERYTHING
$filenames = glob( "$dir*" );

// Start the loop to display the images
foreach ( $filenames as $filename ) {

// Display the images
echo "<img src=\"image.php?photo=".$filename."\" />\n";
}
?>
```

---

Alternative code:

File 1 - resize images ( DO NOT RUN ON THE DIRECTORY MORE THAN ONCE OR ELSE YOU WILL DOUBLE THE AMOUNT OF THUMBS! )

```
// Read the directory and sellect jpg only
$filenames = glob("$dir*.{jpg,JPG}", GLOB_BRACE);

// Start the loop to resize the images
foreach ( $filenames as $filename ) {

// New name 
$name = explode ( '/', $filename );
$newname = $name[0]."/th_".$name[1];

//Resize and save in the same directory
//exec("convert $filename -resize 400x400 -quality 50 $newname");
}
```

?>

File 2 - Display images

```
// Read all the image files into an array that start with th_
$filenames = glob("$dir/th_*.{jpg,JPG}", GLOB_BRACE);

// Display the array contents
foreach ( $filenames as $value ){ echo "<img src=\"$value\"><br>"; }
```

?>

Comment: No luck with this either  , images just do not appear.

Comment: The code in this answer works, you're doing something wrong. Make sure you have write permissions to the folder you're saving the image to. Also, try using the full path of "convert", or try simply exec'ing "convert" see if anything returns. Actually, now that I think about it, have you tried looking at the return value of your exec command?

Comment: ok, this works... or at least displays the images. I created the code above in a file called smashit.php and the file appears to be getting passed, and returned, and displayed properly ... however it does not compress the file size at all ... Maybe I'm misunderstanding the quality bit? My ultimate goal is for the file size to go from 2MB to something smaller so I can use the compressed images as thumbnails.

Comment: in addition, this just about turns the server into a BBQ as the CPU maxes out as does the memory ...

Comment: "in addition, this just about turns the server into a BBQ as the CPU maxes out as does the memory ... –" That is no supprise as that is the reason you do not do things "on the fly". What is your final goal; there is no point in saying I want it to do A then but it has to do B as well and then what I really want is C.

Comment: @Vacek I should have said the second piece of code was added when the OP said the first piece did not work.

Comment: Simple :) I'm going on vacation and I will be uploading pictures from my iPad via FTP to various folders on my website. Each picture will be around 3MB in size and I will have no way to "shrink" the filesize before I upload them. I will have people going to the website and viewing the pictures. Each folder represents a different day of pictures and each day will have a different webpage. I simply want each webpage to grab all the pictures from a folder, show them as thumbnails (smaller filesize the better for loading) and when a thumbnail is clicked on the picture show in original size

Comment: (might use lightbox) ... the important thing here is that a folder could have 50 picures for any given day, and I cannot have the load time be 10 minutes due to 50x3MB of pics loading ...

Comment: I would FTP the photos to a folder on the server then run some code on the server to resize them. You could give them a suffex like th_ and then have an index page that only selects photos with the th_ suffex - you can do that with glob.

Comment: thanks so much. However file 1 above seems to be executing, but no files are created. I unescaped the exec line. My permissions are 755 on the directory and file I just created. I can echo the $filename so I know they are being read just fine .. thoughts? No errors are being thrown at all.

Comment: Ok fixed ... the $newname line was incorrect. Changed it too: 
$newname = "th_".$name[0];

Comment: @Vacek, it would be proper to accept this answer, especially because Bonzo did help you ever so patiently.

Answer (score 0):

### 1. Quotes

You use single quotes in this line:

```
exec( 'convert $read -quality 50 $output' );
```

This can not work, because the variables `$read` and `$output` won't be expanded in **single quoted** strings.

You could use either of the following solutions:

```
exec( "convert $read -quality 50 $output" ); // double quote string, expands variables
exec( 'convert ' . $read . ' -quality 50 ' . $output ); // single quoted string with concatenated variables
```

### 2. $output

You use `$output` in the `exec()` line, but you never fill that variable. It should contain the filename where you want `convert` to put your converted file.

### 3. Debugging

For debugging, you could also output the command you feed into `exec()`:

```
$cmd = "convert $read -quality 50 $output";
echo $cmd;
exec($cmd);
```

Comment: I simply want to read all pictures in a specific directory, compress each one of them on the fly, and display them on my webpage ... all .jpg's ... I'm on a shared server so I do not have access to imagick or this would be simple. I tried the 2 lines above, but no luck.

Comment: I hope it rains every day of your holiday.